# How do I give some space between Y axis and my starting and ending vertical bars?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np  
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure  
plt.style.use('ggplot')  

overs = np.arange(1, 51)  
india_score = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 18, size = 50, dtype = 'int16')  

plt.bar(overs, india_score, width = 0.80, align = 'center', color = 'orange', label = 'Runs per over')  
plt.xlabel('Overs')  
plt.ylabel('Score')  
plt.title('India Inning')  
plt.axis([1, 50, 0, 18])  
plt.legend()  
plt.grid(color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)  
fig = plt.gcf()  
fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)  
plt.show()
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

If you see the bar chart then runs scored in first over and runs scored in last over stick to the Y axis. How can I give some space between Y axis and my first and last vertical bars. I tried the margins function but that is not working

I searched for similar posts but I was unable to understand the solution as I am new to matplotlib. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np  
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure  
plt.style.use('ggplot')  

overs = np.arange(1, 51)  
india_score = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 18, size = 50, dtype = 'int16')  

plt.bar(overs, india_score, width = 0.80, align = 'center', color = 'orange', label = 'Runs per over')  
plt.xlabel('Overs')  
plt.ylabel('Score')  
plt.title('India Inning')  
plt.axis([1, 50, 0, 18])  
plt.legend()  
plt.grid(color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)  
fig = plt.gcf()  
fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)  
left, right = plt.xlim()
plt.xlim(left-1, right+1)
plt.show()
```

`left, right = plt.xlim()` gets the current limits of the x-axis and `plt.xlim(left-1, right+1)` sets the new limits by one step further outside relative to the old limits.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It  worked. However,It will be very helpful if you can describe how                  left, right = plt.xlim()
plt.xlim(left-1, right+1)    works